# Click the button with the HtmlUnit - Java

Tags: java, htmlunit-driver

I am unable to click a button to HtmlUnit , already tried by the name and ID , it does not have a Value, already I put waiting and still nothing .

```
HtmlButton button = (HtmlButton) page2.getElementById("imbInserir");

  try {
  button.click();
  }catch(Exception e) {
      System.out.println("I could not push the button");
      e.printStackTrace();
      return;
  }  
   }
}
```

**Html Page Button:**

```
<input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderConteudoPagina$dtvFiltragem$imbInserir" id="imbInserir" title="Inserir Apontamento" src="../Imagens/inserir.png">
```

[image: button]

Console:

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   htmlunit.Acesso.main(Acesso.java:74)